# Storing 4000 image files per directory

Tags: php, file-upload

So I want to store about 4k images in one directory, like this: `uploads/uniqid()./file.jpg` and `uploads/uniqid()./thumb/file.jpg`

Now, the problem is the way I want to do it, I don't thinks is the best way.

I want to have a table, where I store the active directory name that has less then 4k images in it.

So when a user uploads an image, I will go in that directory count the files, and if it'S less the 4k I will upload the image there, if the are 4000 images in the directory I will create a new directory name using `uniqid()` and put the file in the new directory, I will also update the table with the new active directory name.

I think this solution is ok, except that I will have to count the files each time a user uploads an image, what do you think guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to counting the files would be to add a counter (ie: autoincrement) field to a table, and insert a row in the table when a user uploads a file. You could then use mysql_insert_id() to get the id for the row you just inserted.

Then simply add the following to see if you need to create a new directory:

```
if((mysql_insert_id() % 4000) === 0) {
   //create new dir name
   //insert new dir name into table as active dirname
   //add image to new folder
}
else {
   //add image to active directory
}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of this, I can have my table like this: `dir_name | files` and each time I do an upload I do a ++,and when I create a new folder I reset the counter, so you think my basic idea is ok, I can go with this

Comment: Dont reset the id, just use an auto incremental id. The modulus operator will return 0 every 4000 elements. Updated my answer to make it more clear. By using an auto incremental id you would also have an easy way to get the total number of files.